# How to find the second Tuesday in a month of a given year in C++?

Tags: c++, datetime

For example, given 2019, October, return 12 since the second Tuesday on October 2019 is 12th. I know how to do it in java. I want to implement it in C++, but I do not know what libraries I should use.

```
public int date(int year) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(year, 10, 1);

    if (start.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)
            return start.plusWeeks(1).getDayOfMonth();

    return start.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.TUESDAY)).plusWeeks(1).getDayOfMonth();
```

}

It returns the second Tuesday on October.

Comment: `boost::gregorian::date` is an excellent tool for that.

Comment: now you posted java-code, but tagged your question as c++. If you want to port that function to c++, then give it a try. Do a little bit of googling and have a look into [cpp-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). If you then get stuck on a specific problem, then please feel free to ask for help here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to `boost`, this becomes very easy and somewhat similar to the Java code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

auto date(const int year, const int month) {
    namespace gr = boost::gregorian;

    gr::date d{year, month, 1};

    while(d.day_of_week() != gr::Tuesday) {
        d += gr::days(1);
    }
    d += gr::weeks(1);

    return d.day();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << date(2019, 3); // second tuesday of march 2019 -> 12
}
```

We first obtain a `boost::gregorian::date` object initialised with the first day of the specified month and go forward as long as we don't end up on the first Tuesday. Afterwards, we add one week do our date. Lastly, we return `boost::gregorian::date::day`, which represents the day of the month of the specified date.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler than that messy Java code:

```
auto d = year_month_day{Tuesday[2]/October/year{y}}.day();
```

This uses the [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library that became part of standard C++ in time for C++20.

PS: second Tuesday in October 2019 is the 8th, not the 12th.

Comment: Not only simpler, but much more efficient too.  There's no iteration under the hood with this library.